# Найти координаты точки на сфере на которую указывает другая точка

Tags: геометрия

Мне нужно найти точку на сфере на которую указывает точка.

У меня есть координаты первой точки(point), её yaw/pitch и радиус сферы, мне нужно найти координаты точки на которую она указывает.

X,Y мне удалось найти так:

```
x = point.x + RADIUS*cos(degree2radians(pitch))*cos(degree2radians(yaw));
y = point.y + RADIUS*sin(degree2radians(yaw))*cos(degree2radians(pitch));
z = ?
```

Как мне найти Z?

**Важно: первая точка всегда в центре сферы.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считая, что pitch - угол между радиусом к точке на сфере и плоскостью XY:

```
z = point.z - RADIUS * sin(degree2radians(pitch));
```

Comment: Я уже так пробовал, мне тоже казалось что это верно, но почему-то я получаю не верное значение.

Comment: @AimX - это верное значение. Если Вы утверждаете, что неверное, - аргументируйте.

Comment: Поясню.
При r=653, point.x=1237, point.y=328, point.z=573, yaw(в градусах)=72, pitch(в градусах)=35, я получаю значение Z=950, а должен получить 197. 
P.S. X,Y,Z нужной точки у меня есть, но мне нужно универсальное решение для любых данных.

Comment: А, видимо, положительный pitch меряется вниз от плоскости XY, a широта вверх.

Comment: я не силен в геометрии, если поясните, то буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Я поменял знак в формуле, так как `sin(-alpha) = -sin(alpha)`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все верно.